# Working with circle radials. Subtraction and addition

Tags: objective-c, addition, subtraction

I'm working with magnetic headings and I am struggling a little bit with the math around it.
Let's say I have a heading of 270 degrees, and I turn clockwise 110 degrees. I want the new heading, 020 degrees, as an output and not 380 degrees. Is the best way to do something like this:

> if (x > 360) {  x = x - 360; }

or can I use calculations with M_PI to make it more correct?

Thanks for any replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An angle of `x` degree is equal to any angle `X` which satisfies `X = x [360]` that's modular arithmetic note that `x` can be less then -360 or greater then 720, so in that case, adding or subtracting 360 won't give you the result you're expecting. If you want a pure calculation method by adding or subtracting, you can use this piece of code:

```
if (x >= 360){
   while( x >= 360)
     x -= 360;
   }
}else if (x < 0){
   while( x < 0)
     x += 360;
   }
}
```

Or, more easily, in Objective-C, the operator that gives the value of `X` satisfying the equation below and being in the interval of `[0;360[`,is the `%` operator. You can use it that way:

```
X = x % 360
```

Although, your angles may not be `int` types. Than that operator won't work because it takes `int` as arguments. In this case, you can use the `fmod` or `fmodf` functions. The syntax you would use would then be :

```
X = fmodf(x,360)
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be best way..

```
x = x % 360;
```

Comment: angles may not be integer. I'd use fmod (for doubles) or fmodf (floats)